# strptime() alternative in C for Windows

Tags: c, windows, strptime

I am working on some C code that requires usage of strptime() but unfortunately it is not available in the MinGW-w64 libraries my build system is using. Can someone suggest a C alternative for this functionality ? Note that I am not looking for C++ based solutions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see [Time Routines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/time-management?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to import NetBSD's [strptime.c](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/?rev=HEAD).

I have compiled bits and pieces of NetBSD code on Windows over the years. It's usually easier to make Windows provide a specified interface than to change an application to use the Win32 API.

Comment: There is also a version that has already been modified for MinGW-w64: [strptime.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/master/mingw-w64-libkml/strptime.c)